# How to add DataNode to Cloudera hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am trying to add a Datanode to my existing Single Datanode. Since my Unix server does not have access to Internet , Cloudera Manager is unable to perform the installation as it throws below error.  Is there any other CLI Method to Add Data Node instead of CM?

```
BEGIN yum info jdk
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
http://archive.cloudera.com/cm4/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/4.7.2/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'archive.cloudera.com'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two approaches (I'm keeping this Cloudera-specific since this is what you mentioned).

1) Download tarballs and install everything manually.  There is a guide available [here](https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_path_C.html), and I think it is not a good candidate to be copied here on Stack Overflow, because it is very long and vendor-specific (if the document moves, the title is "Installation Path C - Installation Using Tarballs").

2) For large internal installations, you may consider setting up your own repositories with rpm packages that you can access with yum.  For this you'll need to edit `/etc/yum.repos.d` and link to some accessible host that's going to be your repo server (of course, you'll have to put your files there in advance).  More details [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.7.3/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_custom_installation.html?scroll=cmig_topic_21). You can download rpms [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/4/).  I have never had to do this myself, so I help this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the update  I did install Cloudera Agent using RPM's and again went to Cloudera Manager to Add Datanodes under Hosts--->Add new host how ever I got below error